# Identificar texto despues de caracter, y asignar a label c#

Tags: windows-forms, datagrid

Tengo este form para cargar un archivo txt:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de boton, aqui es donde cargo el archivo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //lines contiene todas las lineas del archivo
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\JR\\Desktop\\TXTS\\MX19080253005013GNNPN8ACYN.htd");


    //estamos mandando las lineas a una cadena string a la clase read
    r.lineas = lines;
    //estamos llenando la el grid con la informacion 
    r.readFile(dataGridView1, ' ');

}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta clase read:

```
class read
    {
        public string[] lineas; //creamos una cadena de string 

        public void readFile(DataGridView tabla, char caracter) //metodo para leer y llenar el grid 
        {


            foreach (var linea in lineas) //mandamos la informacion y la muestra en el grid
            {

                int columnas = tabla.Columns.Count;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in tabla.Rows)
                {

                    int vacios = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < columnas; i++) //quitar espacios
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[i].Value) == string.Empty)
                        {
                                vacios++;
                        }
                    }

                    if (vacios == columnas)
                    {
                        tabla.Rows.RemoveAt(fila.Index);
                    }
                }
                AddRowDataGrid(tabla,linea,caracter);

            }

        } //public readFile

        public static void nombrarTitulo(DataGridView tabla, string [] titulos)
        {
            int x = 0;
            for (x = 0; x <= tabla.ColumnCount - 1; x++ )
            {
                    tabla.Columns[x].HeaderText = titulos[x];
            }
        } // public nombrarTitulo


        public static void AddRowDataGrid(DataGridView tabla, string linea, char caracter)
        {

            string[] arreglo = linea.Split(new string[] { caracter.ToString(),"\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            tabla.Rows.Add(arreglo);

        } //public AddRowGrid 
    }
```

Asi es como se ve archivo txt:

```
*** DATE: 3/7/2019     TIME: 6:42 AM        SN: MX19080344405013GNNPN8ACYN     SW VER: 9.07   Station: ATE08-FOXCONN     TX Cal: 23.42    Individual Tests: FALSE   ***

TEST      DESCRIPTION                                       MIN                    MEASURED                    MAX       UNITS     RESULTS   TIME      
**********************************************************************************************************************************

1      XXXXX                                                XXXXX                   XXXXXX                      XXXX    XXXX        XXXX    XXXXX
       XXXXX                                                XXXXX                   XXXXXX                      XXXX    XXXX        XXXX    XXXXX
       XXXXX                                                XXXXX                   XXXXXX                      XXXX    XXXX        XXXX    XXXXX
       XXXXX                                                XXXXX                   XXXXXX                      XXXX    XXXX        XXXX    XXXXX                           


2      XXXXX                                                XXXXX                   XXXXXX                      XXXX    XXXX        XXXX    XXXXX
       XXXXX                                                XXXXX                   XXXXXX                      XXXX    XXXX        XXXX    XXXXX
```

Esta es la linea 4:

```
*** DATE: 3/7/2019     TIME: 6:42 AM        SN: MX19080344405013GNNPN8ACYN     SW VER: 9.07   Station: ATE08-FOXCONN     TX Cal: 23.42    Individual Tests: FALSE   ***
```

Lo que necesito hacer obtener la informacion de cada uno es decir, 3/7/2019 de Date:, 6:42 AM de TIME: etc... y ponerlos en el form donde estan unos labels los cuales se llenaran con dicha informacion, el nombre de estos son :

> labelDate
>
> LabelTime   LabelSn
>
> LabelSw
>
> LabelStation
>
> LabelTx

Como puedo realizar esta accion?

Comment: Podrías usar expresiones regulares para eliminar ese tipo de cosas.

Comment: Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta, y agregues dos o 3 líneas de como es tu txt, como texto, no como imágen..

Comment: La primera imagen es el txt, esa linea es la 4.

Comment: Pero agregalo como texto, evita usar imágenes, verlo como texto también sirve para ver si la separación son tabulaciones o espacios por ejemplo.. también es más fácil de reproducir que verlo en una imagen..

Comment: listo, ya esta editado.

Comment: Pato. te pido por favor que dejes de hacer lo que estas haciendo. Sabes como funciona el sitio. Porque volviste a borrar una pregunta que estabas haciendo para volver a la pregunta original?

Comment: no habia respuestas alguna  esta antes de editara esta pregunta, solo edite para hacerla mejor a la que estaba, creo que no hay duplicado alguno, entonces creo no hay problema.

Comment: Hiciste una nueva pregunta y eliminaste esta. Y luego eliminaste esa pregunta y recuperaste esta. Cualquier que hubiera estado siguiendo tu problema para darte una respuesta, no pudo terminar (si hubiera sido el caso).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de obtener los valores es utilizar expresiones regulares, el ejemplo que dejo a continuación quizás no resuelva a la perfección el inconveniente que tienes al obtener los valores, pero si te funcionara de guía para que lo adaptes a tú código apoyándote en los enlaces de referencias que dejo al final del post.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string date, time, sn, sw_ver, tx_cal, individual_tests;

    string line = "*** DATE: 3/7/2019     TIME: 6:42 AM        SN: MX19080344405013GNNPN8ACYN     SW VER: 9.07   Station: ATE08-FOXCONN     TX Cal: 23.42    Individual Tests: FALSE   ***";

    date = GetValue(line, "DATE:", "TIME:");
    time = GetValue(line, "TIME:", "SN:");
    sn = GetValue(line, "SN:", "SW VER:");
    sw_ver = GetValue(line, "SW VER:", "STATION:");
    tx_cal = GetValue(line, "TX Cal:", "Individual Tests:");
    individual_tests = GetValue(line, "Individual Tests:", "[*]");
}

static string GetValue(string line, string upperLimit, string lowerLimit)
{
    string pattern = string.Format(@"(?<={0})(.*?)(?={1})", upperLimit, lowerLimit);

    Match math = Regex.Match(line, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (math.Success)
        return math.Value.Trim();

    return "";
}
```

**Método `GetValue`**:
Obtiene el valor que se encuentre entre los parámetros, nombres o sub-expresión. La misma devuelve el valor si coincide la expresión de lo contrario retornara una cadena vacía.

***Parámetros***:

- `Line`: es la cadena donde se obtendrán los valores.
- `upperLimit`: límite superior a buscar (en este caso el nombre del valor a buscar). También es posible pasar cualquier sub-expresión si se da el caso.
- `upperLimit`: límite inferior a buscar (en este caso el nombre siguiente del valor a buscar). También es posible pasar cualquier sub-expresión si se da el caso.

Detalles del patrón: `(?<={0})(.*?)(?={1})` donde `{0} y {1}` son los valores de `upperLimit y upperLimit` respectivamente . Con este patrón obtenemos los valores que se encuentran entre el límite superior y limite inferior.

> **Nota**: el código anterior no esta sumamente testeado, por lo que te tocara verificar el performance e investigar cualquier otra sub-expresión que llegues a necesitar.

---

**Referencias**:

> [Aserción de búsqueda tardía positiva de ancho cero](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_positive_lookbehind_assertion):
>   `(?<= subexpresión )` donde subexpresión es cualquier patrón de expresión regular. Para que se produzca una coincidencia, subexpresión debe encontrarse en la cadena de entrada a la izquierda de la posición actual, aunque subexpresión no esté incluida en el resultado de la coincidencia. Una aserción de búsqueda tardía positiva de ancho cero no retrocede.
>
> [Aserción de búsqueda anticipada positiva de ancho cero](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion):
>   `(?= subexpresión )` donde subexpresión es cualquier patrón de expresión regular. Para que se produzca una coincidencia, la cadena de entrada debe coincidir con el patrón de expresión regular de subexpresión, aunque la subcadena coincidente no se incluya en el resultado de la coincidencia. Una aserción de búsqueda anticipada positiva de ancho cero no retrocede.
>
> [Referencia rápida de expresiones regulares](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference?view=netframework-4.7.2):
>   Una expresión regular es un modelo con el que el motor de expresiones regulares intenta buscar una coincidencia en el texto de entrada. Un modelo consta de uno o más literales de carácter, operadores o estructuras.
>
> [Regex.Match](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2):
>   Busca en una cadena de entrada una subcadena que coincida con un modelo de expresión regular y devuelve la primera aparición como un único objeto Match.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es tan simple como desarmar el string en los pedazos que queres:

```
String cadena = "*** DATE: 3/7/2019     TIME: 6:42 AM        SN: MX19080344405013GNNPN8ACYN     SW VER: 9.07   Station: ATE08-FOXCONN     TX Cal: 23.42    Individual Tests: FALSE   ***";
String Date = cadena.Substring(cadena.IndexOf("DATE:")+5,cadena.IndexOf("TIME:")-cadena.IndexOf("DATE:")-5).Trim();
String Time = cadena.Substring(cadena.IndexOf("TIME:")+5,cadena.IndexOf("SN:")-cadena.IndexOf("TIME:")-5).Trim();
String SN = cadena.Substring(cadena.IndexOf("SN:")+3,cadena.IndexOf("SW VER:")-cadena.IndexOf("SN:")-3).Trim();
Console.WriteLine(cadena);
Console.WriteLine(Date);
Console.WriteLine(Time);
Console.WriteLine(SN);
```

Fijate que en ese ejemplo, vas a ver que sale lo que necesitas de cada caso.

Podes hacer lo mismo para todo el string y pasar el dato al control que vos queres. No necesitar ni desarmar el string, ni pasarlo a un array ni nada de eso.

Comment: Que alguien me explique por qué le dieron negativo al buen @gbianchi

Comment: OP se abra enojado porque lo rete por que hizo la misma pregunta varias veces? @fredyfx

Comment: welcome to the mod's life

Comment: IMHO usar una regex para sacar un texto que siempre es fijo, es sobrecargar el sistema.. pero bue.. ni se va a notar...